# mpi4py: abort() and raise RuntimeError()

Tags: python, error-handling, mpi, abort, mpi4py

Is there a way to use `mpi4py.abort()` and python `raise RuntimeError()` (or any other sort of error) together?  Maybe

```
errstr = 'ARRRGH!!!'
raise RuntimeError(errstr)
mpicomm.abort()
```

or

```
mpicomm.abort()
errstr = 'ARRRGH!!!'
raise RuntimeError(errstr)
```

or some other variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `MPI_Abort` basically terminates all processes within the application, there is no way to combine this with regular exception handling in python. Note that MPI implementations are permitted to abort all processes, not just the one in `mpicomm`.

The only think that would make some sense, it to raise a `RuntimeError` in some local python code, and invoke `mpicomm.abort()` in the exception handler.